# Send jenkins build results to Confluence

Tags: jenkins, confluence

I'm quite new to Confluence and taking a look at the Confluence plugin in Jenkins.
Do you know of any "for dummies" instructions?

Answer (score 2):

There's a plugin for uploading build artifacts to confluence:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Confluence+Publisher+Plugin